# Installing dependency on condition

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a Python package `P` that has requirement `A` and requirement `B3.4`, but `A` has requirement `B4.1`. However, I know P can work just fine with `B4.1` for some cases. I would like to be able to pip install package `P` and only install `B3.4` if another version of `B` is not found in the target environment.

I have tried the following:

- Inheritance from `setuptools.command.install.install` to override install command as explained here: https://blog.niteo.co/setuptools-run-custom-code-in-setup-py/. I tried checking and installing `B` after and before `install.run`
- Trying to import `B` and add `B3.4` as a requirement if the import does not succeeds. It turns  out that `B3.4` is always added, even if `B4.1` is already installed.

Is there any reason for which it may not work? What other alternatives do I have?

Thank you!

Comment: In your requirements in your setup file, you should be able to set acceptable versions

Comment: I don't think you have any **clean** solution, you will have to use some trick. Solutions involving a dynamic check at build-time (i.e. code in `setup.py`) is quite limited, as it won't work once a _wheel_ is built. Solutions involving a dynamic check at run-time are not best practice, and also have lots of issues. A possible work-around I can think of right now, would be to move `P`'s requirement on `B==3.4` to optional requirements (_extras_), but it also has obvious limitations.

Comment: Thank you @sinoroc I was trying to avoid that, but I think you are right in that it sounds like the only possible way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have any *clean* solution, you will have to use some trick.

Solutions involving a dynamic check at build-time (i.e. code in `setup.py`) are quite limited, as they won't work once a wheel is built.

Solutions involving a dynamic check at run-time are not best practice, and also have lots of issues (loading a *module* that was installed *in-process* is tricky).

A possible work-around I can think of right now, would be to move *P*'s requirement on `B==3.4` to **optional dependencies** (*extras*), but it also has obvious limitations. As long as it's clearly explained in the documentation of *P*, and the side effects are clearly stated, I would say that is fair game.